# Как сформировать условия вывода в скрипте (api)?

Tags: javascript

Как можно реализовать условия в скрипте, чтобы при определённом значении менялся вывод кода?

```
      data.forEach((movie) => {
    const movieEl = document.createElement("span");
    movieEl.classList.add("staff");
    movieEl.innerHTML = `<a class="actors" href="/xfsearch/actors/${movie.nameRu}/">
<span>
<img src="${movie.posterUrl}" alt="${movie.nameRu}"/>
<div class="professionText">${movie.professionText.replace(/ы$/, "")}</div>
<div class="nameru">${movie.nameRu}</div>
</span></a>`;
    moviesEl.appendChild(movieEl);
  });
```

Что я имею в виду, получаю информацию по api и вывожу её так

```php
<a class="actors" href="/xfsearch/actors/${movie.nameRu}/">
<span>
<img src="${movie.posterUrl}" alt="${movie.nameRu}"/>
<div class="professionText">${movie.professionText.replace(/ы$/, "")}</div>
<div class="nameru">${movie.nameRu}</div>
</span></a>
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы когда `movie.professionText` равно определённому значению (например, `"человек"`), то тогда бы выводимая ссылка менялась на

```php
<a class="actors" href="/xfsearch/chel/${movie.nameRu}/">
<span>
<img src="${movie.posterUrl}" alt="${movie.nameRu}"/>
<div class="professionText">${movie.professionText.replace(/ы$/, "")}</div>
<div class="nameru">${movie.nameRu}</div>
</span></a>
```

Comment: У вопроса стоит метка "javascript", но судя по коду, это вообще какой-то шаблонизатор и возможно на стороне сервера даже. В данном случае не очень понятно, что вы используете на самом деле, чтобы дать ответ.

Comment: data.forEach((movie) => {
    const movieEl = document.createElement("span");
    movieEl.classList.add("staff");
    movieEl.innerHTML = `<a class="actors" href="/xfsearch/actors/${movie.nameRu}/">
<span>
<img src="${movie.posterUrl}" alt="${movie.nameRu}"/>
<div class="professionText">${movie.professionText.replace(/ы$/, "")}</div>
<div class="nameru">${movie.nameRu}</div>
</span></a>`;
    moviesEl.appendChild(movieEl);
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как мне сделать, чтобы когда movie.professionText равно определённому значению (например, "человек"), то тогда бы выводимая ссылка менялась

Например вот так сделать можно...

```
// тут описываются разные варианты
const obj = {
  "человек": 'chel',
  "человек2": 'chel2',
  def: 'actors'
}
data.forEach((movie) => {
  const movieEl = document.createElement("span");
  movieEl.classList.add("staff");
  // вот тут определяем
  const tp = obj[movie.professionText] ?? obj.def
  // вот вставляем
  movieEl.innerHTML = `<a class="actors" href="/xfsearch/${tp}/${movie.nameRu}/">
<span>
<img src="${movie.posterUrl}" alt="${movie.nameRu}"/>
<div class="professionText">${movie.professionText.replace(/ы$/, "")}</div>
<div class="nameru">${movie.nameRu}</div>
</span></a>`;
  moviesEl.appendChild(movieEl);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли! А можно как то сделать несколько вариаций значений? т.е например `const tp = movie.professionText == "человек" ? 'chel' : 'actors' elise const tp = movie.professionText == "человек2" ? 'chel2' : 'actors2'`

Comment: @PortalPC-, из твоего сообщения не понятно чему будет равняться `tp` если `movie.professionText` не будет равняться `"человек"` или `"человек2"`. У тебя там два разных значения `'actors'` и `'actors2'`...

Comment: @PortalPC-, в свой пример я добавил разнообразие вариантов для `movie.professionText`... Но если там ничего не подойдет - `tp` будет равен только `'actors'`.

Comment: Сейчас у меня так const profession = movie.professionText == "Режиссеры" ? 'directors' : 'actors' по вашему совету. Я бы вот хотел немного разнообразить вариации ссылки, т.е помимо этих двух нужно еще несколько вариантов актёр, режиссер, сценарист, оператор

Comment: @PortalPC-, в своем примере я уже показал как можно "разнообразить" такое - создать объект с парами ключ-значение.

Comment: Да увидел, всё отлично работает, сразу не увидел что код изменён. После этого const tp = obj[movie.professionText] ?? obj.def никакой знак ставить не надо? Всё конечно работает, но после этого выражения часть кода красным загорелось

Comment: @PortalPC-, у меня ничего не "горит"... Поставь `;` или сам файл закрой/открой... Может синтаксический анализатор в редакторе твоем заглючил... :-\

Comment: Всё равно горит, да и ладно всё работает, да и ошибок нет не каких. Наверное что то из-за анализатора в редактора. Спасибо вам большое!